# JCrop showPreview function explanation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jcrop

I'm having a tough time getting my head around exactly what this function does and why it does it. The function comes from JCrop, which is a pretty standard jQuery cropping plugin. This function is responsible for calculating how to show a little preview image beside an image that you're intending to crop. You make a selection on your image and the preview displays.. well.. a preview.

Here is the function, from JCrop's example page:

```
function showPreview(coords)
{
    var rx = 100 / coords.w;
    var ry = 100 / coords.h;

    $('#preview').css({
        width: Math.round(rx * 500) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * 370) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
        });
}
```

It may also be important to note that the JCrop instance has an option where the aspect ratio is set to 1, the `preview` div is 100px wide and 100px in height.

Here is a link if you'd like to see the code and even try it out.

http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail

I don't understand many of the numbers.. rx * 500? Why? ry * 370? Why? A top to bottom run through of this logic would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These parameters 500 and 370 are the exact height of the picture that is being cropped. The one in the demo is with 500px width and 370px height.

On the preview (on right) is also shown the whole picture. When you change your selection it is updating the parameters of the image. You are calculating how big the selection box is with

```
 width: Math.round(rx * 500) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * 370) + 'px',
```

In order to set the height of the preview.And also calculate how far are you from the left side and the top by using these two:

```
 marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
```

It is actually calculating the selected area size and how far it is from left and top so it can send the correct parameters to the preview area.

The AspectRatio is actually showing the ratio between width/height - so if you are cropping 100x100 picture it would be 100/100 = 1 , however if you are cropping 250x100 picture it would be 250/100 = 2.5.